# PostgreSQL problem while trying to access database

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could somebody help with PostgreSql? I'm trying to access already existing database Employees, but it says that I do not have this database. How to fix this problem? Here is the screenshots
[image]

Also here is why all my data from local PostgreSQL local server located

[image]

And Here is database that I'm trying to access through out command line[image]

Comment: Please, use plain text in your question, not images somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You should user "-d" for specifiy database name.

Try this:

psql -U your_username -d employees